# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /raw/storage/1693-44A7/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190525_080405.jpg (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, try-catch

When I run my Android app then got an error. I am using below code for compress image and upload to firebase. please help me how to fix it. any other method work then please tell me about that method

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable 
  Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 507 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        ImageUri = data.getData();

        File actualImage = new File(ImageUri.getPath());
        File imgFile = new File(actualImage.getAbsolutePath());

        if (!imgFile.exists())
        {
            try {
                imgFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Log.e("actual_image", String.valueOf(imgFile));

        try {
            Bitmap compressedImage = new Compressor(this)
                    .setMaxWidth(300)
                    .setMaxHeight(250)
                    .setQuality(50)
                    .compressToBitmap(imgFile);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            compressedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
            byte[] final_image = baos.toByteArray();

            Log.e("Final_image", String.valueOf(final_image));



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error_image", String.valueOf(e));
        }
    }

}
```

E/Error_image: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /raw/storage/1693-44A7/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190525_080405.jpg (No such file or directory)

Comment: The error is pretty clear, the file is not found `FileNotFoundException` ensure that you have permission to `READ/WRITE` on the application.

Comment: Already give permission READ and Write

Comment: This method work on image cropper library but without image cropper library not work